# javascript regex, replace multiple instances with a single one in multiline string

Tags: javascript, regex, multiline

I have a multi-line string in javascript as follows:

```
"<p> </p>
<p> </p>
<p> </p>
<p> </p>
"
```

I am trying to remove the extra instances of `<p> </p>`, so I am trying to use the following regex.

```
var content = getContent() // This returns the string mentioned above.
content = content.replace(/(<p> <\/p>)+/g, "<p> <\/p>");
```

But this does not seem to work. Most probably because the string is a multi-line string ? I have tried the above regex with a single line string and it works fine. After reading a little more documentation about  javascript regex, I realized that we need to use the `m` modifier to deal with multi-line strings. So I changed the regex to:

```
content = content.replace(/(<p> <\/p>)+/gm, "<p> <\/p>"); // note the `m` modifier
```

But it still does not work. any clues ?

Comment: How is it not working? What is it returning? It also looks like your replacing the match with itself (`replace(/(<p> <\/p>)+/gm, "<p> <\/p>");`), am I missing something there?

Comment: @Rob It returns the same string, Guess you are missing the `+` quantifier ?

Comment: Duh, should've reread the title after reading your question. :P

Answer (score 2):

You should replace all spaces (including new lines) :

```
content = content.replace(/(<p>\s*<\/p>\s*)+/g, "<p> <\/p>");
```

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/IjoTIpIR/1/)

Comment: This works, but I am a little confused, why `\s` and not `\n` for new lines ?

Comment: @Amyth You could use \n but it's frequent to have spaces you ignore in your html, due to them being invisible. So it's safer to use \s in this case.

Answer (score 0):

se this replace:

```
content = content.replace(/(<p> +<\/p>\n*)+/g, "<p> </p>");
/=> <p> </p>
```

Comment: `[\s\S]` Is *any char*, including precious content.